# How to use css "ime-mode" in Chrome browser

Tags: css

I'm setting up CSS "ime-mode: active;" to set up input text box to Korean language when pages load.

I tried to set css ime-mode like blow code.

```
input[type='text'] { 
    -webkit-ime-mode:active;
    -moz-ime-mode:active;
    -ms-ime-mode:active;
    ime-mode:active;
}
```

"ime-mode: active;" works in Explorer but doesn't work in Chrome.

developer mode in chrome shows this message "invalid property value" in terns of "ime-mode".

anybody had same issue as me?

any ideas is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ime-mode), `ime-mode` is deprecated and is likely to be dropped in browsers that still support it:

> This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.

In the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ime-mode#Browser_compatibility) on that page, Chrome is listed as not supporting this feature. Given the above, it likely never will.