# How to add IME mode in textbox of Asp.net(VB) web form?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web, ime

I have a textbox on my webform and I want to open IME when the textbox is focused.
I found that 'ImeMode' on internet but I can't find that property in my project.
I'm using visual studio 2019 for asp.net( vb) project.
Can someone tell me what I need to get imemode for my project?
noted: I need to open IME for japanese characters.
thank you.

---

Edit

May be it is not a right answer but it did work on IE so I will put the code here.

I added css style in my textbox for ime.

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" style="ime-mode:active"></asp:TextBox>`
`<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" style="ime-mode:disable"></asp:TextBox>`

Comment: What is IME mode?

Comment: @Chetan input foreign languages for textbox like japanese,korean etc . I think ;

Comment: Looks like IME mode is not popular and supported for web input controls.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ime-mode

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57684379/how-to-use-css-ime-mode-in-chrome-browser

Comment: @Chetan thz, I added ime mode in my css style and it did work for now. But as you said, ime can't support on chrome or edge so I tested on IE.